# Laravel 5.5 locale as prefix in url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

At the moment I have in my `routes/web.php` the following:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => '{locale?}', 'middleware' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class ], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {

    Route::get( '/', 'LandingController@index' )->name( 'home' );
    Route::get( '/hero/create', 'HeroController@create' )->name( 'hero.create' );
} );
```

This doesn't really work as it should be.

What I want is to have an url like this:

```
/create/hero    # should work with the default locale
/fr/create/hero # should use the french locale
/nl/create/hero # should use dutch locale
/               # should work with the default locale
/fr             # should use the french locale
/nl             # should use dutch locale
```

So I want the locale parameter optional at the beginning of the url.
So far what I've managed to achieve is only to get the urls working when specifying the locale myself. I always get a `not found` message when I don't manually specify the locale.

I know I should be able to do it like this:

```
Route::get('/path/{id}/{start?}/{end?}', ['as' => 'route.name', 'uses' => 'PathController@index']);

public function index($id, $start = "2015-04-01", $end = "2015-04-30")
{
    // code here
}
```

But I think that's a but would mean I have to set the default locale in every controller which is a bit ugly in my opinion. Also, I think that this should be possible in a more elegant way in Laravel.

How can I set a default value for the `locale` prefix in my url?

Comment: Have you considered redirecting the `/` and `/create/hero` to the default locale version instead of serving real content at those urls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to think about routes generated deeply. And **never use prefix as optional** , so to make work all url give change in route like this

```
Route::get( '/', 'LandingController@index' )->name( 'home' );
Route::get( '/hero/create', 'HeroController@create' )->name( 'hero.create' );

Route::group( [ 'prefix' => '{locale}', 'middleware' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class ], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
    Route::get( '/', 'LandingController@index' )->name( 'home' );
    Route::get( '/hero/create', 'HeroController@create' )->name( 'hero.create' );
} );
```

Here is the short description in your way

```
/               # should work with first above route 
/create/hero    # should work with first above route
/fr/create/hero # should work with route inside prefix
/nl/create/hero # should work with route inside prefix
/fr             # should work with route inside prefix
/nl             # should work with route inside prefix
```

It can be solve either to put optional ({locale?}) at the last not in between, or you can just put route into a variable and put in both condition, I mean outside prefix and inside prefix.

```
$heroRoutes = function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
    Route::get( '/', 'LandingController@index' )->name( 'home' );
    Route::get( '/hero/create', 'HeroController@create' )->name( 'hero.create' );
}
Route::group( [ 'middleware' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class ], $heroRoutes );
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => '{locale}', 'middleware' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Locale::class ], $heroRoutes );
```

Comment: I know I can do it like that. But when someone decides to share an url like /hero/create I don't think it should result in a 404. I'd like that route to be available as well and use the default language. Therefore I'd like the language parameter to be optional.

Comment: @SheperdOfFire: If you use `/hero/create` as you said , first word `hero` would be the value of `locale` not as you expected and you will get `404` error. I hope you got the point what I mean ?

Comment: Yes I understand, but that would also mean I'd have to create every route twice. I was hoping there would be an automated solution for that

Comment: It can be solve either to put optional (`{locale?}`) at the last not in between, or you can just put route into a variable and put in both condition, I mean outside prefix and inside prefix.

Comment: You can get some idea from other [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9741) and [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032537/laravel-optional-prefix-routes-with-regexp)