# Laravel prefix language prefix if it has

Tags: php, laravel, routes, prefix

I would like to use language selector in Laravel. I used this sollution: [Laravel optional prefix routes with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032537/laravel-optional-prefix-routes-with-regexp). 
It works fine. I store location in database eg.: en, de. **I would like to use the prefix only if the site has multiple language set in database.** So how can I prevent use `'prefix' => '{lang?}'` if i have only one language.

Here you are my web.php (Route):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang?}', 'middleware' => 'locale', 'where' => ['lang' => "en|de"], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('article', 'ArticlesControllerController@index');
});
```

With 1 language:

```
/home
/article
```

With multi language:

```
/en/home
/de/home
/en/article
/de/article
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well in this situation, you can use the Closure function and if condition. Set the prefix based on the values as it is possible to declare a Closure with all your routes and add that once with the prefix and once without:

```
$languageList = 'fr|en';

$optionalLanguageRoutes = function() {
    Route::get('/test', 'DashboardController@test');
};

// Add routes with lang-prefix
if ($languageList) {
    Route::group(
        ['prefix' => '/{lang}/', 'where' => ['lang' => $languageList]],
        $optionalLanguageRoutes
    );
}

// Add routes without prefix

$optionalLanguageRoutes();
```

Declare empty languageList when you don't have languages.